# Is it possible to remove elements in a page layout in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-2.0, page-layouts, containers

When I read the documentation on page-layouts (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html#layout-types-page) I see that the following instructions in this XML document are allowed:

- `<container>`
- `<referenceContainer>`
- `<move>`
- `<update>`

Since `<referenceBlock name="block.name" remove="true" />` isn't one of the allowed instructions how can I remove a certain element in a specific page layout?

What I want for the top-categories is a whole other page design. I don't need certain containers and blocks for this design. For these categories I only want to show child categories and not the products.

The thing I've done now is, added the following lines in my page layout:
(in `design\frontend\Vendor\Name-of-theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\catalog-blocks.xml`)

```
<move element="category.image" destination="delete"></move>
<move element="category.description" destination="delete"></move>
<move element="category.products" destination="delete"></move>
<move element="page.main.title" destination="delete"></move>
```

In the `design\frontend\Vendor\Name-of-theme\Magento_Theme\layouts.xml` I addded:

```
<layout id="catalog-blocks">
    <label translate="true">Catalog Blocks</label>
</layout>
```

I gave all the top-categories this catalog-blocks page layout in the admin.

Then in the main layout (`design\frontend\Vendor\Name-of-theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`) I added:

```
<referenceBlock name="delete" remove="true" />
```

So the whole delete block will be deleted, with all the things I moved here, in the page layout. This works well! It achieves exactly what I want but the whole thing seems to me a little hackish.

Is this considered being a good practice? If not, what would be a good alternative?

**Edit 1**: Changed the `remove`-tag in my question with the right one to avoid confusion.

**Edit 2**: Some more information about the files and file-locations.

Answer (score 13):

What about:

- creating a new container (instead of a block)
- move your blocks to the container
- remove the container

Something like this:

```
<container name="delete" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="delete"/>

<move element="category.image" destination="delete"></move>
<move element="category.description" destination="delete"></move>
<move element="category.products" destination="delete"></move>
<move element="page.main.title" destination="delete"></move>

<referenceContainer name="delete" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I've done. My point is: this feels weird. Is this the only workaround? Why is it that  Magento didn't build this feature into the page_layouts and is there a good reason for not being able to remove blocks?

Comment: @11mb it's slightly different than what you have done as in my post I'm creating and referencing a container in one single file (the page layout xml) whereas in your question you're using a block and several XML files. However that's a great question I'm not sure why Magento didn't build this feature in the page_layouts

Comment: @11mb feel free to create an issue on the Magento 2 GitHub repo to address that problem, it's definitely an interesting issue and I'm sure there's a good reason behind it

Comment: I see what you've have done here. I think it's a slightly better approach indeed. I will test it out and come back here.

Answer (score 7):

This is the best practice for remove any block or container in magento 2.
You can pass `name attribute` inside `name` in below element.

```
<referenceBlock name="block.name" remove="true" />
```

You can search inside magento 2 system, you have find many places syntax same as above.

Its magento recommendation way.If attribute remove="true" then add the element to list remove from that layout.

In magento 1 `<remove> element` is valid but in Magento 2 you have to set syntax same as above.

Comment: Thx! I think I have to rephrase the question a little. Is it possible to use `<referenceBlock name="block.name" remove="true" />` (I was wrong about the `remove` tag) in a page-layout  directly since `referenceBlock` isn't allowed either. I still should `move` an element to a 'delete-container'  and then delete it in the main layout file. Which seems strange to me.

Comment: **referenceBlock** is used when already block is defined with name. otherwise its not useful. ex. `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">` , in this case you can use `<referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />`

Comment: I'm aware that the block should exist on beforehand. But in a page layout I can't use all the generic layout instructions as described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex. (I edited my question), so I can't use referenceBlock

Comment: in which page are you working for now and which element wnat to delelte?

Comment: I added some more information in the question. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Hi @RakeshJesadiya, I do i remove  following <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" /> in catalg_product_view.xml

Answer (score 1):

The page layouts are only supposed to be used to create a wireframe/structure of the page and not for smaller modifications such as removing blocks.

To remove a block for only your new layout I think the best way is to create your own layout handle and make the modifications in there. For example you could create catalog_category_toplevel.xml that uses your new wireframe/layout and remove the blocks in there.

As this is more of a back-end task I don't feel comfortable enough to provide instructions for this sorry :( These two articles from Alan Storm may help you with this:

- http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc
- http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/141212337575/adding-custom-layout-handles-in-magento-2

### TL:DR

If you wish to do this and follow best practice you need to create a new layout handle.